# How to catch an error coming from another async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch

I have a script which contains 2 async functions. The first one gets Geo Location data from a promisified `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPostition` and then does reverse Geo Location using [geocode.xyz](https://geocode.xyz). I have the whole function in a try/catch block which then does a console.log of the error, if one is generated. I am able to generate an error by modifying the url to one that cannot be resolved. So far, this is working fine.

The problem is when I am calling that async function from another async function. In the second function, I also have a try/catch block, the problem is, the catch never gets executed.

My goal is to create a TextNode with the error and append it to a div, instead of appending the Geo Location data to the div. Here is my JS code:

```
const options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
};

const getPosition = () => {
  return new Promise((resovle, reject) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resovle, reject, options);
  });
};

const getAddress = async () => {
  try {
    const pos = await getPosition();
    const { latitude: lat, longitude: lng } = pos.coords;
    const resGeo = await fetch(`https://ggeocode.xyz/${lat},${lng}?geoit=json`);
    console.log(`The resGeo response is ${resGeo}`);
    const dataGeo = await resGeo.json();
    const streetNumber = dataGeo.stnumber;
    const streetName = dataGeo.staddress;
    const suburb = dataGeo.city;
    const address = `${streetNumber} ${streetName}, ${suburb}`;
    return address;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`An error has occured: ${err.message}`);
  }
};

const populateData = async () => {
  try {
    showLoader();
    const address = await getAddress();
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");
    addressContent = document.createTextNode(`Your address is: ${address}`);
    container.appendChild(addressContent);
    hideLoader();
  } catch (err) {
    errorContent = document.createTextNode(
      `An error has occured: ${err.message}`
    );
    container.appendChild(errorContent);
  }
};

const showLoader = () => {
  const loader = document.querySelector("#loader");
  loader.classList.add("display");
};

const hideLoader = () => {
  const loader = document.querySelector("#loader");
  loader.classList.remove("display");
};

const button = document.querySelector("#button");

button.addEventListener("click", populateData);
```

Here are 2 code pens - [fetch working](https://codepen.io/turtleracer/pen/oNpKgVY) and [force error (wrong DNS name)](https://codepen.io/turtleracer/pen/OJzKPdv)

Comment: Hi T.J., I just tried to edit my question and use on-site snippets, however, the environment doesn't seem to support the geolocation API. I am getting the Console error '
An error has occured: Geolocation has been disabled in this document by permissions policy.'

Comment: Yeah, the Stack Snippets have issues. :-| Well, you seem to have included all the necessary code in the question anyway (which is great). :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is when I am calling that async function from another async function. In the second function, I also have a try/catch block, the problem is, the catch never gets executed.

If you mean that the `catch` block in `populateData` never gets triggered by an error in `getAddress`, that's because you've explicitly handled the error with a `try`/`catch` in `getAddress`. This is no different than with synchronous functions: If you handle the error, it stops propagating up the call chain.

Either:

1. Don't handle the error (usually you don't want to handle errors anywhere but in the entry point functions — event handlers and such) so that it propagates
2. If you **need** to handle it in `getAddress`, either re-throw it from the `catch` in `getAddress` or have `getAddress` return a failure value (`null` for instance).

But your `catch` handler in `getAddress` just logs and suppresses the error, so #1 would be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you so much T.J. Crowder, I will test this out!